# Why Android permissions must be explicitly declared by the developer?

Tags: android, android-permissions

As specified on [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions)

> Because Android sandboxes applications from each other, **applications
>   must explicitly share resources and data. They do this by declaring
>   the permissions they need for additional capabilities** not provided
>   by the basic sandbox, including access to device features such as the
>   camera.

In my opinion, it would be more useful to automatically detect the required permissions while compiling the source code. In this way, depending on the classes and methods used in the source code of an application, the compiler could detect the required permissions. So, why Android permissions must be explicitly declared by the developer?

Comment: Maybe because to minimize the system's effort in detecting permissions by traversing thousands of your methods

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj but it needs to do this anyway (in order to compile it). I don't believe the overhead would be significant.

Comment: @KonradMorawski  yes, it was a bad guess by me. Alex's answer and comments has provided a very good explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is the developer who knows which permissions his application has.

Consider this: a developer does not want his app to access contacts and yet, by mistake, the app accesses them.

If permissions are detected from code, not stated explicitly, such an error would pass unnoticed.

Comment: The same can be said for libraries that you may include and not want to code review the entire thing.

Comment: You're right... However, how to deal with the opposite problem (permissions declared but not used)? All explicitly declared permissions will be listed during application installation, including permissions which are actually not used in the source code...

Comment: Then it is you own fault if a user doesn't want to install your app because you requested too many permissions